# XSLT: Processing hierarchical XML data using XSLT

Tags: xml, recursion, xslt, tree, hierarchical

I have the below XML document. Under each node there are many sub nodes, but I am interested only in few of them.
My target is to run xslt on it to generate a Json output contains only the elements I am interested in them.

The approach that I took is to process it as XML first (apply all data transformation, renaming, output only elements I am interested in ...etc) then apply another xslt to convert it to Json (I found some ready xslt online that can do that).

My issue right now mainly in the recursive part, I can't do it correct, I tried for-each/apply-templates/call-template but I still have hard time with it.

```
<MainDoc>
    <MetaData>
        <Name>MainDoc Name</Name>
        <Date>MainDoc Date</Date> <!--not interested in this element-->
    </MetaData>
    <ContentList>
        <Content/>
        <Content/>
        <Content><!--Want to process last content only-->
            <BuildList>
                <Build>
                    <Steps>
                        <Step><!--want to process all of them-->
                            <StepContentParent>
                                <StepContent>
                                    <Title>myTitle1</Title>
                                    <Details>myDetails1</Details>
                                    <Date>Step Date</Date> <!--not interested in this element-->
                                </StepContent>
                            </StepContentParent>
                            <Steps><!--Could be empty or could be the same as the previous Steps (recursion ) -->
                                <Step><!--want to process all of them-->
                                    <StepContentParent>
                                        <StepContent>
                                            <Title>myTitle1.1</Title>
                                            <Details>myDetails1.1</Details>
                                        </StepContent>
                                    </StepContentParent>
                                    <Steps/><!--Could be empty or could be the same as the previous Steps (recursion ) -->
                                    <SubDoc><!-- could be empty -->
                                        <SubDocInstance>
                                            <DocInstance>
                                                <MainDoc><!-- Same as Root (recursion ) -->
                                                    <MetaData>
                                                        <Name>Sub Doc Name</Name>
                                                    </MetaData>
                                                    <ContentList>
                                                        <Content/>
                                                        <Content/>
                                                        <Content><!--Want to process last content only-->
                                                            <BuildList>
                                                                <Build>
                                                                    <Steps>
                                                                        <Step><!--want to process all of them-->
                                                                            <StepContentParent>
                                                                                <StepContent>
                                                                                    <Title>Sub Doc myTitle1</Title>
                                                                                    <Details>Sub Doc myDetails1</Details>
                                                                                </StepContent>
                                                                            </StepContentParent>
                                                                            <Steps><!--Could be empty or could be the same as the previous Steps (recursion ) -->
                                                                                <Step><!--want to process all of them-->
                                                                                    <StepContentParent>
                                                                                        <StepContent>
                                                                                            <Title>Sub Doc myTitle1.1</Title>
                                                                                            <Details>Sub Doc myDetails1.1</Details>
                                                                                        </StepContent>
                                                                                    </StepContentParent>
                                                                                    <Steps/><!--Could be empty or could be the same as the previous Steps (recursion ) -->
                                                                                    <SubDoc><!-- could be empty -->
                                                                                        <SubDocInstance>
                                                                                            <DocInstance>
                                                                                                <MainDoc/><!-- Same as Root (recursion ) -->
                                                                                            </DocInstance>
                                                                                        </SubDocInstance>
                                                                                    </SubDoc>
                                                                                </Step>
                                                                                <step/>
                                                                                <step/>
                                                                            </Steps>
                                                                            <SubDoc><!-- could be empty -->
                                                                                <SubDocInstance>
                                                                                    <DocInstance>
                                                                                        <MainDoc/><!-- Same as Root (recursion ) -->
                                                                                    </DocInstance>
                                                                                </SubDocInstance>
                                                                            </SubDoc>
                                                                        </Step>
                                                                    </Steps>
                                                                </Build>
                                                            </BuildList>
                                                        </Content>
                                                    </ContentList>
                                                </MainDoc>
                                            </DocInstance>
                                        </SubDocInstance>
                                    </SubDoc>
                                </Step>
                                <step/>
                                <step/>
                            </Steps>
                            <SubDoc><!-- could be empty -->
                                <SubDocInstance>
                                    <DocInstance>
                                        <MainDoc/><!-- Same as Root (recursion ) -->
                                    </DocInstance>
                                </SubDocInstance>
                            </SubDoc>
                        </Step>
                        <Step>
                            <StepContentParent>
                                <StepContent>
                                    <Title>myTitle2</Title>
                                    <Details>myDetails2</Details>
                                </StepContent>
                            </StepContentParent>
                            <Steps><!--Could be empty or could be the same as the previous Steps (recursion ) -->
                                <Step><!--want to process all of them-->
                                    <StepContentParent>
                                        <StepContent>
                                            <Title>myTitle2.1</Title>
                                            <Details>myDetails2.1</Details>
                                        </StepContent>
                                    </StepContentParent>
                                    <Steps/><!--Could be empty or could be the same as the previous Steps (recursion ) -->
                                    <SubDoc><!-- could be empty -->
                                        <SubDocInstance>
                                            <DocInstance>
                                                <MainDoc/><!-- Same as Root (recursion ) -->
                                            </DocInstance>
                                        </SubDocInstance>
                                    </SubDoc>
                                </Step>
                                <step/>
                                <step/>
                            </Steps>
                        </Step>
                        <step/>
                        <step/>
                    </Steps>
                </Build>
            </BuildList>
        </Content>
    </ContentList>
</MainDoc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using the identity transformation with `apply-templates` has "recursion built-in" I am not sure what the problem is, you just use it as the starting point (e.g. in XSLT 3 with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`) and then add empty templates matching the elements you want to strip and/or templates matching for those elements you want to rename or transform otherwise:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="MainDoc/MetaData/Date"/>

  <xsl:template match="StepContentParent/StepContent/Date"/>

  <xsl:template match="ContentList/Content[not(position() = last())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26my

Comment: Thank you @Martin

May be my problem is not clear, my bad. I will try my best to make it more clear just please bear with me.
Your approach looks good, but the thing is the number of elements to strap is a huge compared to number of elements I am interesting in. Also I don't want the exact tree in the out put instead I want to build a new tree with different structure.

Another point; I am using Dot Net 4.5 for transformation, I set xslt version to 3.0 so "shallow-copy" work, it work but it generate the out put from the values only (without the xml tags)!

Comment: @osamaibrahim, as for using XSLT 3 with the Microsoft .NET framework, for that you need to use an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9, available for .NET as version 9.9 on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/ and Sourceforge (file SaxonHE9-9-1-7N-setup.exe in https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.9/).

Comment: XSLT 3 also allows you the other way around with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` and then spelling out e.g. `<xsl:template match="MainDoc | MetaData"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`. That way anything you don't explicitly set up a template for would be skipped. With both approaches or XSLT in general, if you want to change the structure, you add the templates doing that.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen Working with XSLT 3.0 is much better than 1.0, it is shame that Microsoft still refuse to implement it in Dot Net.
shallow-skip worked good for me.

Comment: I will appropriate if you can clarify a use case when for-each could be used while "mode on-no-match" is used?

Comment: @osamaibrahim, I don't think it makes sense to ask and answer such a rather broad question for a use case here in a comment to a specific question. In general using `apply-templates` is called pushed based processing while using `for-each` pull based. Look into any XSLT introduction for those terms and I am sure you will find a better introduction than someone can write in a comment on StackOverflow.